# Reminder: Hyperlink citations are freeform text

Tags: discussion

The practical upshot is that you don't have to worry about numerical sequencing or having to rearrange things if edits are made at a later date. Definitely useful for tag wiki stuff, or any other giant blob of hyperlinks (i.e. RFCs) that you're throwing together.

This started as a PSA on using RFC numbers/names in hyperlinks, but I'm adjusting the format so that 1) I can accept my own answer, and 2) people can share their own silly citation tricks.

Comment: Didn't know about this, I always thought only index numbers were allowed. Great to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## RFC links

This is pretty obvious when you think about it, but still neat.

### Example:

```
This is a link to [RFC 1796][1796].

So is [this][rfc1796].

[1796]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1796    
[rfc1796]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1796
```

### Result:

This is a link to [RFC 1796](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1796).

So is [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1796).

---

Comment: Since I apparently can't edit it... It's also worth pointing out that you can also use the syntax: `[RFC 1796][]` so long as the later citation is the same string (i.e. `[RFC 1796]: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1796`).

Comment: You can even use `[RFC 1796]` in this case, which is the most readable version anyway (in unformatted markdown sources).